# Keep getting notifications after uninstalling Skype

Tags: uninstall, skype, software-uninstall

I uninstalled Skype thru terminal using `sudo purge` command but still getting notifications about who is online/offline and chat messages.

How to get rid of it?

Comment: `sudo apt purge skype-bin`

Comment: Are there any Skype process running?

Comment: How do I check it?

Answer (score 0):

I had this trouble too.

When I would log out of Skype on Ubuntu I would still get notifications. I decided to uninstall the program.

After running `sudo apt-get purge --auto-remove skype:i386` I was finding that I could still get notifications.

I ran `ps aux | grep skype` to see what running processes I still had. And I saw one running process. I killed that process with `kill process#` and restarted and have not seen any notifications.